# Accessing individual events in a sliding window in Siddhi

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am new to Siddhi and CEP. I want to get the first and the last events in a current sliding window.

I have tried:

```
from WeightStream#window.length(4) as W
select W[1].weight as weight1,  W[last].weight as weightLast
insert into AlertStream;
```

and

```
from w = WeightStream#window.length(4)
select w[1].weight as weight1,  w[last].weight as weightLast
insert into AlertStream;
```

For the window containing [1, 2, 3, 4] output should be [1, 4].

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to access windows in an index based way. Instead to achieve this requirement you can use [counting patterns](https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-5.x/query-guide-5.x/#counting-pattern). Below is a sample which will work in sliding manner.

```
from every( e1= WeightStream) -> e2= WeightStream<3> 
select e1.weight as weight1, e2[last].weight as weightLast
insert into AlertStream;
```